# Supremum of set in more than 2 dimensions: i.e. supremum of set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let us consider $\mathbb{R}^n, n\geq 2$. For simplicity, let's say $n=2$ (but I'm wondering about when $n>2$ as well). lets consider the set
$$
Z=\{ (x,y)\mid x+y\leq 2\}
$$

Does this set have a supremum? If so, what is it?

I am confused because there are point that are neither $\leq$ or $\geq$ other points. For example, $(2,0)$ has nothing greater than it. However, $(2,0)$ is neither $\leq$ or $\geq (0,2)$. So would these both be supremums, along with $(1,1), (1.5,.5)$ etc.? I guess the answer may be that $(2,2)$ is the supremum, which is not in this set, but then it seems that in higher dimensions the supremum would often not be in the set...

I guess, upon a little further thinking, **my question is** are points like $(2,0)$ that are in the boundary, but not greater than or equal to everything (because we are in higher dimensions) supremum or maximum?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. What the order in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have do define an order on $\Bbb R^n$.  In $\Bbb R^1$ we have the usual order, but in $\Bbb R^n$ there isn't one.  You could use lexicographic order, where $(a,b) \gt (c,d)$ if $a \gt c$ or $a=c, b \gt d$.  You also seem to be assuming that $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$.  In that case your $Z$ is an isosceles right triangle with corners $(0,0), (2,0), (0,2)$ In the lexicographic order, $(2,0)$ is the greatest point in or on the triangle and is the supremum.  Alternately you could define a partial order as $(a,b) \gt (c,d)$ if $a \gt c$ and $ b \gt d$  In this case the supremum would be $(2,2)$ as that is the least point greater than all the points of the triangle.  If you don't restrict to $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$ your set is the half plane below $x+y=2$  It does not have a supremum in either of these orders.  The same thing happens in higher dimensions.

Comment: I was assuming that $(a,b)>(c,d)$ if $a>c$ and $b>d$, $(a,b)\leq (c,d)$ if at least one component $>$ and all other components at least $\geq$. I thought that was standard, but I guess not. Thanks.

Comment: That is a fine order (though your $\le$ should be $\ge$) but it is partial.  You can't compare $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$, for example.  Depending on what you are doing, that may not be a problem.